# how do i pass a block to a method whose name ends with equals sign?

Tags: ruby

this sounds weird doesn't it?

```
class Dummy
  def foo=(value); end
end

Dummy.new.foo = 1 { |x| x } # => syntax error
Dummy.new.foo=(1) { |x| x } # => syntax error
```

i tried every permutation of blanks, parenthesis, commas; no luck. i'm puzzled. i never suspected methods ending with '=' were special. is it a bug? is it intended? if intended, why? is it documented? where? please share insight.

thanks

ps. ruby is 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.1]

Comment: It might be helpful if you described the code that you wanted to write, and why you thought that passing a block to a method ending in `=` made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax sugar for methods ending in `=` does make it special. You can still do things like pass multiple arguments to that method, or pass a block, but not in any pretty or convenient manner:

```
class Foo
  def bar=(a,b=nil)
    p [a,b]
    if block_given?
      yield "hi"
    else
      puts "No block"
    end
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar = 42
#=> [42, nil]
#=> No block

f.bar = 42, 17
#=> [[42,17], nil]
#=> No block

f.send(:bar=,42,17) do |x|
  puts "x is #{x.inspect}"
end
#=> [42, 17]
#=> x is "hi"
```

Another way in which these methods are special is that when called with the syntax sugar they evaluate to the right hand value, not the return value of the method:

```
class Foo
  def bar=(a)
    return 17 # really explicit
  end
end

f = Foo.new

x = (f.bar = 42)
p x
#=> 42

x = f.send(:bar=,42)
p x
#=> 17
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much that the methods themselves are special, but more to do with how Ruby deals with assignments (like `foo = bar`). First the right hand side is evalulated, then the left hand side is evaluated and the appropriate action is taken. If the left hand side is an object attribute, then the appropriate setter method is called.

So in your example:

```
Dummy.new.foo = 1 { |x| x }
```

First ruby tries to evalulate `1 { |x| x }`, which is what causes the syntax error.

`Dummy.new.foo=something` doesn't actually mean "call the method named `foo=`", but actually means something more like "evalualate `something`, and then determine what `` `Dummy.new.foo `` is, and if it looks like an object attribute, add `=` to the name and call that method". This is why `Dummy.new.foo=` and `Dummy.new.foo =` both work the same way.

You can call these methods using `send`, and can pass a block with this:

```
Dummy.new.send "foo=", 2 do
  puts "HI"
end
```

This is because with `send` you can explicitly name the method you want to call.

Of course the end result is that methods ending in `=` seem to have some "special" behaviour you need to be aware of, but it might be useful to understand what's actually going on.